# How to add vertices in the given code?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I use this code

```
h[x_, y_, 0] := 
 Prepend[Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6] + x, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + y}, {k, 6}], {0, 0}]

h[x_, y_, n_] := 
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Flatten[Table[{Cos[2 Pi k/6] + #1, Sin[2 Pi k/6] + #2}, {k, 6}] & @@@
     h[x, y, n - 1], 1]]

 Line[{##}] & @@@ EdgeList@NearestNeighborGraph[h[0, 0, 1]] // 
  Graphics
```

and the result is

[image]

How can I ask Mathematica to add black dots at all vertices?

Comment: `h[0, 0, 1]` give the coordinates of all points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VertexList` does what you want:

```
{Line[{##}] & @@@ EdgeList@#,PointSize[Large],Point[{##}]&@@@VertexList@#}&@NearestNeighborGraph[h[0, 0, 1]] // 
  Graphics
```

[image: Image output of code.]

To control the thickness of the lines, you would adjust the designation of `Large` within the `Thickness` that is placed before `Line`, just as you would control the size of the points by adjusting `Large` within the `PointSize` placed before `Point`:

```
{Thickness[Large],Line[{##}] & @@@ EdgeList@#,PointSize[Large],Point[{##}]&@@@VertexList@#}&@NearestNeighborGraph[h[0, 0, 1]] // 
  Graphics
```

[image: Image output of code.]

Comment: Thanks. And how can we change the edge thickness?

Comment: That is a separate question, but easily addressed. Just add `Thickness[x]` before the `Line` part, where x is some number that is your desired thickness. I’ll show this in an update.

Comment: @sara96 please see the update as requested.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is (1) to use the options `VertexShapeFunction` and `VertexStyle` in `NearestNeighborGraph` and (2)  wrap the output with `Show` to get a `Graphics` object:

```
Show @ NearestNeighborGraph[h[0, 0, 1], 
   VertexCoordinates -> h[0, 0, 1],
   VertexStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], Darker @ Gray], 
   VertexShapeFunction -> (Point[#] &)]
```

[image]

```
Head @ %
```

> ```
>  Graphics
> ```

Use `EdgeStyle` to style the edges:

```
Show @ NearestNeighborGraph[h[0, 0, 1], VertexCoordinates -> h[0, 0, 1],
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], Blue, AbsoluteThickness[15]], 
  VertexStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], Red], 
  VertexShapeFunction -> (Point[#] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And how can we change the edge thickness?

Comment: @sara96, please see the update.